# php-version/index.php was not found on this server

Tags: php, url, file-not-found

i have an ubuntu installation and a  folder in my **/var/www** named site1 with files in it(including index.php and others) 
but when i try to visit this site by typing ***localhost/site1*** i get the error that says:

> The requested URL /site1/php-version/index.php was not found on this
>   server.

please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

the usual path is :

```
/var/www/html/
```

Try again by putting your site1 folder in *html* folder inside *www* and make sure you have placed the content in the right place!